# How to use Shuffling to improve rng?

Tags: c#

Following a pseudo code implementation of Bays & Durham I'm trying to sort a random sequence of numbers using the inbuilt random in c#.

The pseudo code I'm following is:

1. An array of random numbers (V) is generated
2. A random number is generated (Y)  - the seed should be the last number in the array
3. Generate a random Index (y) using the following formula:    (K*Y) / m
   Where:
   K - Size of the array
   Y - The random number generated
   M - The modulus used in the random number generator used to populate the array
4. The element at position Y in the array i.e. V[y] is returned
5. The element at position Y to in the array is set to Y itself i.e. V[y] = Y

```
int[] seq = GetRand(size, min, max);
int nextRand = cRNG.Next(seq[seq.Length-1]);

//int index = (seq.Length * nextRand) / [Add Modulus];

return seq;
```

The first couple steps I could follow. Now, I need to return a shuffled array so the pseudo code needs to be modified a little.

Few pointers on above code:
cRNG -> The instance name of Random
GetRand(...) -> Has a forloop using cRNG

Now what I'm not understanding are the following:

1) Given I'm using the inbuilt random how can I get the modulus used to populate the array since it's simply a for loop using cRNG.Next(min, max)

2) The last step I don't fully understand it

Any help would be quite appreciated!

[Edit]

Following Samuel Vidal solution would this work? (Assuming I have to do it all in a single method)

```
public static int[] Homework(int size, int min, int max)
{
    var seq = GetRand(size, min, max);
    nextRand = cRNG.Next(min, max);

    var index = (int) ((seq.Length * (double) (nextRand - min)) / (max - min));
    nextRand = seq[index];
    seq[index] = cRNG.Next(min, max);

    return sequence;  // nextRand that should be returned instead.
// Made it return the array because it should return the newly shuffled array hence the for loop
}
```

Comment: What is the use case for this?

Comment: To improve the sequence of random numbers by using Shuffling

Comment: Yeah, I get that.  Is this a card game?

Comment: No real use case. Just to showcase an improvement on a random sequence of numbers.

Comment: OK, well what do you mean by "improvement?"  Is this just an academic exercise/homework?  Because otherwise, there is already a PRNG available to you that is better than the one you or I could write.

Comment: Yea, it's an academic exercise so we have to stick with the pre-requisites of using the inbuilt random in c#.

Comment: I think your step 2 is already wrong, because you are not using the last number in the array as *the seed*.

Comment: Guess I understood it wrongly. Thought it meant the last element in the array.

Comment: @Doomsayer Yes, but you are not using it as *the seed*

Comment: Forgive me, but I'm not getting how to use it as the seed. Could you maybe illustrate how it should be done? Thanks!

Comment: Oh yeah sorry! Just to be clear, if I had to put it in a for loop as I need to return a shuffled array, would it need further modification or a simple new array (or on existent one) is sufficient? Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is the following,

```
var index = (int) ((sequence.Length * (double)(randNum - min)) / (max - min));
```

But I suggest that you fill the array with unaltered random numbers from the source, then that you map the output of you random number generator to the interval `[min, max[` as a overloading method `Next(int min, int max)` that calls the output of your Bays-Durham shuffle process.

```
public class BaysDurham
{
    private readonly int[] t;
    private int y; // auxiliary variable

    // Knuth TAOCP 2 p. 34 Algorithm B

    public BaysDurham(int k)
    {
        t = new int[k];

        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        {
            t[i] = rand.Next();
        }

        y = rand.Next();
    }

    public int Next()
    {
        var i = (int)(((long) t.Length * y) / int.MaxValue);
        y = t[i];
        t[i] = rand.Next();
        return y;
    }

    public int Next(int min, int max)
    {
        long m = max - min;
        return min + (int) ((Next() * m) / int.MaxValue);
    }

    private readonly Random rand = new Random();
}
```

Generally, it is a great software design principle to have [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

---

Test code:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    const int k = 30;
    const int n = 1000 * 1000;

    const int min = 10;
    const int max = 27;

    var rng = new BaysDurham(k);

    var count = new int[max];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var index = rng.Next(min, max);
        count[index] ++;
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Expected : {1.0 / (max - min):F4}, Actual :");

    for (int i = min; i < max; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{i} : {count[i] / (double) (n):F4}");
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Expected : 0.0588, Actual :
10 : 0.0584
11 : 0.0588
12 : 0.0588
13 : 0.0587
14 : 0.0587
15 : 0.0589
16 : 0.0590
17 : 0.0592
18 : 0.0586
19 : 0.0590
20 : 0.0586
21 : 0.0588
22 : 0.0586
23 : 0.0587
24 : 0.0590
25 : 0.0594
26 : 0.0590
```